# Where did the YouTube comment translate button go?

Tags: youtube

I am logged in, I don't speak Russian or whatever it is, and I cannot see a translate button:

[image: YouTube example]

and NO: disabling ad block does not help.

I remember a long time ago, I had this option. Not any more.

Is the translate button disabled for more people?

Answer (score 1):

The comment-level translations have been removed when the Google+ commenting system was introduced IIRC.

Chrome's in-browser translations only are available if the page looks sufficiently foreign enough to Chrome, if you always want a translation option, you can use the [Google Translate Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb)

Answer (score 1):

YouTube removed that feature a while back and it's no longer available. Try installing the [TransOver Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transover/aggiiclaiamajehmlfpkjmlbadmkledi). After installing you'll see page containing:

> TransOver
>     offered by artemave
>
> **TransOver Options:**
>
> Translate into  [Select default target language] when I  [click on word]
>
> [more options]
>
> Save

After saving, reload the YouTube page you were viewing. Press mouse left button to drag over foreign language comment and release it at the end of the comment, the translated text will appear in a bubble on the upper right.

Answer (score 0):

I find this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-comment-translate/alaejlmlpgcffloicejpccebbeeibemo/related) quite helpful.

It adds a "translate" button in comments.